# Can every symmetric positive semi definite matrix can be written as $A=B^TB$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there any exception to the statement, "Every symmetric positive semi definite matrix can be written as $A=B^TB$"?

Comment: If ***Every** symmetric and positive semi definite matrix can be written as $A=B^TB$*, would there be an exception while using the word **every** ?

Comment: Yup, I am pretty sure there is an exception. If you do not know the answer please do not troll around.

Comment: It is not trolling ... this is truth: **Every** symmetric and positive semi definite matrix can be written as $A=B^TB$ (real case) and there is NO exception.

Comment: If you have a counterexample, then you shall show it

Comment: I am not trolling. Theorems and Lemmas in mathematics use strict word casing and if they state "every" it means every without exceptions. Every Lemma and Theorem also has its proof.

Comment: I (somewhat  belatedly it appears) edited your question for clarity and grammar.  Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

No exceptions.  At least over $\Bbb R$, there are no exceptions.

Since $A$ is symmetric, it can be diagonalized by some orthogonal matrix $O$; call the resulting diagonal matrix $\Lambda$:

$\Lambda = O^T A O; \tag 1$

here

$\Lambda = \operatorname{diag} (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n), \; n = \operatorname{size}(A), \tag 2$

where the $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$; since $A$ is positive semi-definite, each $\lambda_i \ge 0$; since each $\lambda_i \ge 0$, $\sqrt \lambda_i$ is well defined for every $i$, $1 \le i \le n$; set

$B = \operatorname{diag}(\sqrt \lambda_1, \sqrt \lambda_2, \ldots, \sqrt \lambda_n); \tag 3$

we have

$B^T = B \tag 4$

and hence

$\Lambda = B^2 = B^TB; \tag 5$

from (1),

$A = O \Lambda O^T, \tag 6$

since

$O^TO = OO^T = I; \tag 7$

thus by (5) and (6),

$A = O \Lambda O^T = O B^2 O^T = OB^TBO^T = OB^TO^T OBO^T = (OBO^T)^T OBO^T; \tag 8$

we see that

$(OBO^T)^T = (O^T)^TB^T O^T = OBO^T; \tag 9$

thus $OBO^T$ is symmetric positive semidefinite as is $A$.

***Done!!!***

Comment: @anWhy:  thanks for the spelling help!  Cheers!